# How can I restore a CSS file?

Tags: windows, notepad++

I have a huge CSS file that I was editing in Notepad++ when my computer restarted. My CSS file was saved, but after the restart it changed. The CSS code disappeared and there is a long line with `NULLNULLNULLNULLNULL [...]`. The size of the CSS file is correct. How can I restore this file? I have not backed up the CSS file and it took me a long time to create.

edit:
I saved out from Browser cache. But when the computer is restarted I reopened the google chrome and the browser is downloaded my empty css to cache. So I saved it from Firefox cache what I runned yesterday so I only lost 12 hours from my work and my life not all file and weeks:S

Comment: Sorry, but I think you've pretty much lost it for good. Unless you've already got some good data recovery tools and know how to use them, I would say that even for a very large CSS file, it will be quicker to rewrite it. Every developer I know has been through something like this. It's amazing how no-one bothers with backups until they've suffered at least once in this way. I guess it's one of those lessons that everyone has to learn the hard way. But on the bright side, re-doing work almost always ends up being quicker and better than the first time.

Comment: @David, if you register your account and associate it with your [SO] account, then you will have full access to edit your question and leave comment on answers to it.

Comment: Always work on a copy... Hindsight is always 100%, but this is a lesson that seems to always need being learned by experience by most.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users:

**Right-click the file or folder, and then click Restore previous versions**